# gflags dialog box doesn't open

Tags: windows, gflags

I am currently trying to debug a memory leak in one of my applications (yeah, that crap again...), and trying to set `gflags` settings, but the dialog won't open up. I installed the Windows 10 SDK (I am on Windows 7 x64), but it said it works on Win7 as well in the description, so why can I not use it at all?

If I start `gflags` from command line, nothing at all happens, no error, no feedback, nothing.

Anybody an idea as to what might be happening on my system?

Comment: Admin/UAC issue? Try running it from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I did run it from an admin console. Thats not it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=278979, you'll need to wait for a new version (that apparently doesn't exist as of Jan 2017) that contains `gflagsui.dll`

> Known issue that will be fixed in an upcoming release. You should be able to use 
>   the version of GFlags that is installed with any of the 8 or 8.1 kits, or copy 
>   the gflagsui.dll from those.
>
> You can also use GFlags via the command-line: 
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549566(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try opening an elevated command prompt.

cd to install folder
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64)

Type gflags /?

It will probably tell you you only get the dialog box if gflagsui.dll is available, but there is no info how to get it.
(if you don't use an elevated command prompt you'll get UAC, then you'll see a console window open and quickly exit)

So for now you'll need to use the command line...